# Unable to Access Casted Void Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am creating a linked list that contains nodes with the "dataItem" of a void pointer. The purpose of this is in order to be able for the Node to contain any kind of data. However, I am unable to access the void pointer's data, even when that data is casted to the correct type.

My code looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct Student
{
    char stuName[51];
    char stuMajor[5];
    double GPA;
    char stuID[10];
}student;

typedef struct Node
{
    union{
        void *dataPtr;
        int countr;
    }dataItem;
    int  link;
    struct Node* next;
}node;
void readData(struct Node *);

void main(){
    node head;
    node temp;
    readData(&temp);
    student *ptr = (student *)(temp.dataItem.dataPtr);
    printf("%s    %d", ptr->stuName, ptr->GPA);//breaks here because unable to access memory
}

void readData(struct Node *link)
{
    link = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    student *ptr = (student *)malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    printf("enter the student name : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]", ptr->stuName);
    printf("enter the student's major : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]", ptr->stuMajor);
    printf("enter the student GPA : ");
    scanf("%lf", &(ptr->GPA));
    printf("enter the student ID : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]", ptr->stuID);
    link->dataItem.dataPtr = ptr;
}
```

I know I definitely have a pointer wrong somewhere I'm not unsure how. I also have the node within my `readData` function point to a new malloc of Node because I want a new node each time `readData` is called for when I implement the linked list further.

Comment: Here `student *ptr = (student *)(temp.dataItem.dataPtr);` the cast is completely unnecessary. As well as here `link = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));`. And so on... And this `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior, you should never `fflush()` an input stream. Did you include any headers at all? and `main()` does return a value, `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is very broken,

1. You didn't include any header file, you need at least `stdlib.h` for `malloc()`, and `stdio.h` for `printf()` and `scanf()`.
2. Your `main()` definition is wrong, because `main()` must return `int`.
3. You `fflush(stdin)` which is undefined behavior.
4. You ignore the return value from `scanf()`.
5. You assume that `malloc()` always returns a valid pointer.
6. You called `readData()` which is not declared yet.

But the most important mistake, is that you passed `node temp`'s address to `readData()` and you `malloc()`ed it, but you didn't return a pointer to it, thereby losing all the changes made inside `readData()` which will not work anyway because it's undeclared at the moment you called it.

I fixed your code, because I know that you didn't like my answer, but check out the fixes which are related to the answer, and now it works as I expected

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Student
{
    char stuName[51];
    char stuMajor[5];
    double GPA;
    char stuID[10];
} student;

typedef struct Node
{
    union{
        void *dataPtr;
        int countr;
    } dataItem;
    int          link;
    struct Node* next;
} node;

void readData(struct Node **link);


int main()
{
    node    *head;
    student *ptr;

    readData(&head);

    ptr = head->dataItem.dataPtr;
    if (ptr != NULL)
        printf("%s\t%g", ptr->stuName, ptr->GPA);
    return 0;
}

void readData(struct Node **link)
{
    student *ptr;
    if (link == NULL)
        return;
    *link = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (*link == NULL)
        return;
    memset(*link, 0, sizeof(node));

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return;
    printf("enter the student name : ");
    if (scanf("%50[^\n]%*c", ptr->stuName) != 1)
        ptr->stuName[0] = '\0';

    printf("enter the student's major : ");
    if (scanf("%4[^\n]%*c", ptr->stuMajor) != 1)
        ptr->stuMajor[0] = '\0';

    printf("enter the student GPA : ");
    if (scanf("%lf%*c", &(ptr->GPA)) != 1)
        ptr->GPA = 0;

    printf("enter the student ID : ");
    if (scanf("%9[^\n]%*c", ptr->stuID) != 1)
        ptr->stuID[0] = 0;

    (*link)->dataItem.dataPtr = ptr;
}
```

I also added some safety fixes to `scanf()` adding the length modifier to prevent buffer overflow, and also remove the trailing `'\n'` with `"%*c"` specifier, it will not work if multiple spaces follow the value, but you can test it meanwhile just pressing <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd>, if you want more sofisticated input, you should use something else instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: 1. these header files are included, i thought it was obvious that they would be
2. main does not have to return int, and will only return a warning if it does not

Comment: It's not obvious and it's a common cause of problems. Since your compiler didn't complain about `readData()` so it's reasonable to think that you didn't include header files. Implicit function declaration is your enemy, and you seem to ignore that because you didn't declare `readData()` before calling it. The same would happen if you fail to include the headers, not having compiler warnings enabled, will make the code compile without any problem, which would not mean that there are no problems.

Comment: @beckah `main()` does not have to explicitly return a value, because it's an exception to the usual compiler rules - it can be defaulted. But `main()` must be of type `int` except for some embedded applications, where it does not return.

Comment: "thereby loosing all the changes" - it's _losing_ not _loosing_, "loosing" is not a word.

Comment: @davmac sorry, english is not my native language.

Comment: @iharob No need to apologise (it's a common enough mistake even amongst native English speakers)

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
void readData(struct Node *link)
{
    link = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

You throw away the `link` parameter value that was passed in, instead assigning it a new allocation via `malloc`. This is your most significant problem, I think. A simple fix would be to delete the line performing the `malloc`.

Comment: It is indeed, and creating a node of a linked list which is not a pointer, doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a *pointer to a pointer* (or address of a pointer) to a node to the readData() function. readData allocates a new node and fills it; what happens in your code is that readData() gets a *copy* of the address of temp, overwrites the copy of this address with a new address, the one obtained from malloc (which is invisible to the calling code in main()) and then fills that malloc'ed object. Upon return from readData the malloc'ed object is inaccessible.

What you wanted to do is this:

```
void main(){
    node head;
    node *tempAddr; // pointer
    readData(&tempAddr); // pass address of that pointer
```

and then use `*tempAddr` in main instead of `temp`.

```
void readData(struct Node **linkAddr)
{
    node *link = *linkAddr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

[...]
```

unwind would complain that you should not cast the result of malloc, but I think it's fine. I also do not care about the return value of main, or its arguments.

Comment: "You want to pass a pointer to a pointer (or address of a pointer) to a node to the readData() function" - that is one possible interpretation; another is that the `readData` signature is correct, and that the caller should allocate the node.

Comment: @davmac Well, the fact that the OP *does* allocate the node in `readData` strongly supports my interpretation, I would think ;-)

Comment: I think the fact that OP passes in already allocated node, and that the parameter type is `struct Node *`, are equally strong in supporting the alternate interpretation.